# apache server php version not being update

Tags: php, apache, xampp

my machine: macOS Sierra 10.12.3

I am currently working on a project that requires some `PHP v.>=5.6` features. When I start my virtual php server with `XAMPP 1.8.3` and check the php info it tells me the version is `5.5.11`.

I tried updating the php version following this tutorial https://jason.pureconcepts.net/2016/09/upgrade-php-mac-os-x/
upon updating my local `.bash_profile` path and checking php -v I get the upgraded php version `PHP 7.1.1 (cli) (built: Feb 13 2017 10:05:49) ( NTS )`

But when I check the phpinfo on my apache server run by xampp I still see `5.5.11` I updated the `httpd.conf` file and commented the old php versions out and implemented the new one, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
<IfDefine JUSTTOMAKEAPXSHAPPY>
#LoadModule php4_module        modules/libphp4.so
#LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
LoadModule php7_module        /usr/local/php5/libphp7.so
</IfDefine>
```

Any other ideas?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to install a new version of [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html).

Another solution would be to install Apache/PHP from [homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Comment: Worked well. Wanted to do this as last resort. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you update the try apache conf file? It should be in "xampp" directory. Anyway you can just download a new version xampp, e. g. from here https://www.apachefriends.org/ru/download.html